# Where does filter:invert(1) go in shorthand background image css

Tags: css

I'm coding a short css button with a small image using base:64. I'd like to invert the base:64 image without inverting the linear-gradient background color. I could be less lazy and just create an invert of the base:64 image, but I feel I can just do this quicker in CSS however I can't figure out where to place the filter:invert(1) in my css shorthand. Thoughts?

Button looks like this, I just want the icon to be inverted from black to white using filter:invert(1)

https://gyazo.com/13913ed0d5713b5c62892d5f90be7518

```
:host {
background:url('
data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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
')  no-repeat  center 15% / 35%,  linear-gradient(rgb(32,56,71), rgb(13,135,199)) top left / cover no-repeat;
background-color: rgb(13,135,199); /* Incase Gradient Fails */
border-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters apply to the whole element and all its ancestors.
You can not target a single part of this element, nor can you target only one `background-image`.

One solution would be to place the background-image to be filtered on a pseudo-element:

```css
.host {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(32, 56, 71), rgb(13, 135, 199)) top left / cover no-repeat;
  background-color: rgb(13, 135, 199);
  /* Incase Gradient Fails */
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  position: relative;
}
.host::before {
  filter: invert(1);
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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')  no-repeat  center 15% / 35%
}
.host:hover::before {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="host"></div>
```